# How can I combine different similar new commands as a single new command?

Tags: macros

For example, I have created multiple commands as

```
\newcommand{\A}{\mathcal A}
\newcommand{\B}{\mathcal B}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathcal C}
```

Is it possible to combine all those commands as a single one, like the following?

```
\newcommand{\*}{\mathcal *}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly the desired (but very imprecise) syntax offered by the OP, but something that might work for you.  Note this will not check if `\A`, `\B`, or `\C` already exist, and will instead overwrite any extant definition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\makemathcal[1]{
  \readlist\mylist{#1}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\mylist[]{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname\z\expandafter\endcsname
      \expandafter{\expandafter\mathcal\expandafter{\z}}%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\makemathcal{A,B,C}

$\A \ne \B > \C$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps a slightly improved (yet decidedly more dangerous) syntax would be to take advantage of the `pgffor` list specification:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand\makemathcal[1]{
  \foreach\z in{#1}{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname\z\expandafter\endcsname
      \expandafter{\expandafter\mathcal\expandafter{\z}}%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\makemathcal{A,...,Z}

$\A \ne \B > \Z$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: haha, thanks. This is a workaround.

Comment: @whatsname One problem with your desired syntax is it is all inclusive, so that `\a`, `\l`, `\i`, etc would all be REdefined, since they exist.  So, somehow, you need to limit the application, which I do by specifying an enumerated list to cover the extent.

Comment: @whatsname Please see the addendum to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This second one is a better solution. Then, I don't need to type all the 26 letters. :)

Comment: @whatsname it's a really bad idea to over-write standard commands such as `\O` and `\H`

Comment: Øver use of this will go bőőm

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for your suggestion. But in my case, I don't use the standard definition of `\O` and `\H` very often, and I also want to make a consistent redefined command. Probably, I can exclude those from the list.

Comment: @whatsname but as the text of my previous comment shows, it breaks text that don't use those commands explicitly at all.  With editor support you should be able to enter `\mathcal{A}` with very few key strokes or use `\let\zz\mathcal` and `\zz A`. If you make extensive use of such macros then eventually they will end up in some shared conference proceedings and things will break or you will cite a reference with bibtex that has an Ø and things will break, or ...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, you are right. Probably, I can use your first solution, and then only put the letters I want in that enumerate list. In my writing, I use `\mathcal A` a lot, so I thought the easiest way would be defining `\mathcal A` as`\A`.

Comment: @whatsname To avoid `\H` and `\O`, you can break it into three steps: `\makemathcal{A,...,G}\makemathcal{I,...,N}\makemathcal{P,...,Z}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes haha, thanks. Another workaround.

Comment: @whatsname -- You may not consciously use `\O` or `\H` but they often turn up unbidden in names in bibliographies.  Journal editors will hate you.

Comment: @barbarabeeton :) I have never thought of this potential problem.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do it is using

```
#1
```

as general entry.

Look at my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\calll}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}

    \begin{document}

    $\calll{A}$

    $\calll{B}$

    $\calll{C}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

In this way, you can solve your problem in a very simple and elegant way.

Comment: Thanks. But if I write $\calll{A}$, then it is the same as writing $\mathcal{A}$. :)

Comment: Except in this case, `\calll{A}` is only two keystrokes less than `\mathcal{A}`, and a bit more obtuse.

Answer (score 4):

There is no “wildcard” feature, but it's possible to emulate it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{xparse} % uncomment if running LaTeX prior to 2020-10-01

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\makelettercommands}{mmm}
 {% #1 = template
  % #2 = wrapper (for instance \mathcal)
  % #3 = list of ranges
  \whatsname_mlc:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__whatsname_mlc_range_seq
\seq_new:N \l__whatsname_mlc_list_seq
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_step_inline:nnn { ee }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \whatsname_mlc:nnn
 {
  % set a scratch function to the template
  \cs_set:Nn \__whatsname_mlc_name:n { #1 }
  % map the list of ranges (or single letters)
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #3 }
   {
    \__whatsname_mlc_do:nnn { ##1 } { #1 } { #2 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__whatsname_mlc_do:nnn
 {% split at a possible -
  \seq_clear:N \l__whatsname_mlc_list_seq
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__whatsname_mlc_range_seq { - } { #1 }
  \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l__whatsname_mlc_range_seq = 1 }
   {% no range
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__whatsname_mlc_list_seq { #1 }
   }
   {% range
    \int_step_inline:een
     { `\seq_item:Nn \l__whatsname_mlc_range_seq { 1 } } % first item is start of range
     { `\seq_item:Nn \l__whatsname_mlc_range_seq { 2 } } % second item is end of range
     { \seq_put_right:Nx \l__whatsname_mlc_list_seq { \char_generate:nn { ##1 } { 11 } } }
   }
  \cs_set_protected:Nn \__whatsname_mlc_def:n
   {
    \cs_new_protected:cpn { \__whatsname_mlc_name:n { ##1 } } { #3 { ##1 } }
   }
  \seq_map_function:NN \l__whatsname_mlc_list_seq \__whatsname_mlc_def:n
 }

% just for a check, show the commands
\NewDocumentCommand{\showcs}{m}
 {
  \texttt{ \token_to_str:N #1 ~->~ \cs_replacement_spec:N #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\makelettercommands{c#1}{\mathcal}{A-C,E}
\makelettercommands{#1}{\mathcal}{D}
\makelettercommands{#1#1}{\mathbb}{C,H,N,Q,R,X-Z}
\makelettercommands{#1frak}{\mathfrak}{a-z}

\begin{document}

$\cA+\cC+\cE+\D+\ZZ+\YY-\afrak$

\showcs\cA

\showcs\ZZ

\showcs\zfrak

\end{document}
```

I can't recommend defining `\A` to `\mathcal{A}`, better using something a little more complex that carries some semantics. For instance `\cA` and so on.

In the example I do `\NN` and so on for the most common number sets; but note that `\AA` is already defined. In the `\mathbb` example, I use `Y-Z` to show the usage of mixed specs (single letters and ranges).

As you see, in the first argument to `\makelettercommands` we have `#1` acting as a wildcard for the letters specified in the third argument.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using this template, I can easily create many self-defined commands. Also, it took me some time to understand your code. :)

Comment: @whatsname Note that `\usepackage{xparse}` is only needed if you run an outdated LaTeX released prior to 2020-10-01

Comment: You are right. I do run an old version.