# Use pgffor to define a new command?

Tags: foreach

I'm trying to use `pgffor` to define a new command for `\boldsymbol\mathsf` like the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,amsmath}

\newcommand\makemathsfbf[1]{
    \foreach\a\b\c in{#1}{
        \expandafter\gdef\csname\a\b\c\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{%
            \expandafter\boldsymbol{\mathsf\expandafter{\a}}
        }
    }
}
\makemathsfbf{AAA,BBB,...,ZZZ} % {AAA,BBB, CCC, DDD, ..., ZZZ}

\begin{document}
$\AAA$ % = $\boldsymbol{\mathsf A}$
\end{document}
```

I want to use the above command,  i.e., `\AAA`, to replace `\boldsymbol{\mathsf A}` and so on. However, I could not make it to work. How should I modify it?

Comment: First, it is not obvious what follows AAA.  AAB?  BBB?  If I can't guess, how is the computer supposed to?  As it stands, you should only be using `\abc` (or some other macro) instead of `\a\b\c`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo You are right. I changed the list to make it more clear. Also, I tried `\abc`. Unfortunately, it didn't work out.

Comment: what John meant is that apart from other considerations `AAA,BBB,...,ZZZ` is not a valid loop specification for pgf (or any other language I know)

Comment: Also, you only need \expandafter for \gdef so that you don't redefine \csname instead of the expanded version.

Comment: `\boldsymbol\mathsf{A}`  would be the same as `\boldsymbol{\mathsf}{A}` You are missing the `{}` for `\boldsymbol` but you want to loop from A to Z not  an undefined sequence from AAA to ZZZ, then construct the csname  from three copies of the loop variable

Comment: `expandafter\boldsymbol{` expands `{` which is not expandable,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle :) :) Thanks. I made this from the answer `https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/594722/181831`.  I think I need to go through a document to learn how to use this command.

Comment: For some reason the loop is treating `AAA,BBB,...,ZZZ` as a single entry rather than a list.

Comment: @JohnKormylo pgffor treats the argument as a literal list unless the first item is "an incrementable thing" (which AAA isn't)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to define a loop AAA ... ZZZ you need A, ....Z but the pgf for loop isn't really helping here I would use

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bm,amsmath}

\makeatletter
\count@=1
\loop
\expanded{\noexpand\bmdefine\csname\@Alph\count@\@Alph\count@\@Alph\count@\endcsname
   {\noexpand\mathsf{\@Alph\count@}}}
\ifnum\count@<26
\advance\count@\@ne
\repeat


\begin{document}
$\mathsf{A}+\AAA$


$\mathsf{G}+\GGG$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will run, but you will need to come up with a way to generate {AAA,BBB,...,ZZZ}.  Maybe `\Alph{\i}\Alph{\i}\Alph{\i}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\makemathsfbf[1]{
    \def\mylist{#1}
    \foreach \abc in \mylist {
        \expandafter\protected@xdef\csname\abc\endcsname{
            \boldsymbol{\mathsf{\abc}}
        }
    }
}
\makeatother

\makemathsfbf{AAA,BBB,ZZZ} % {AAA,BBB, CCC, DDD, ..., ZZZ}

\begin{document}
$\AAA$
\end{document}
```