# I am trying to pass a command array to the new command or a definition with a `for` loop with `includesvg`

Tags: macros, foreach, svg, genealogytree

I have learned from the following questions:

- ["For loop" in newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20341/for-loop-in-newcommand)
- [Use pgffor to define a new command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/615220/use-pgffor-to-define-a-new-command)
- [\foreach with \newcommand how to use them together?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207985/foreach-with-newcommand-how-to-use-them-together)

I was trying to pass an ancestries list as an array with a new command or a definition or a new command with a definition as an array to the same new command or the same definition.

Here is the small code:

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\newlength{\mypx}
\setlength{\mypx}{0.013889in}

\newcommand\Ancestries[1]
{
    \def\ancestrieslist{#1}
    \foreach \ancestry in \ancestrieslist 
    {
        \includesvg[width={10\mypx}]{assets/images/flags/twemoji/\ancestry.svg}\par
    }
}

\begin{document}

    \linespread{1.5}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \genealogytree
        {
            parent
            {
                g[id = 01, male, box = {title = Self}]
                {
                    \textbf{Ancestries}\\
                    \Ancestries{argentina, brazil, italy, portugal, spain}\\
                }
            }
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I also tried two other ways:

```
\newcommand{\Ancestries}[1]
{
    \foreach \x in {#1} 
    {%
        \includesvg[width={10\mypx}]{assets/images/flags/twemoji/\x.svg}\par%
    }
}

\def\Ancestries#1
{%
  \foreach \x in {#1} 
  {%
    \includesvg[width={10\mypx}]{assets/images/flags/twemoji/\x.svg}\par%
  }
}
```

The result should look like:

```tex
\textbf{Ancestries}\\
\includesvg[width={10\mypx}]{assets/images/flags/twemoji/argentina.svg}
\includesvg[width={10\mypx}]{assets/images/flags/twemoji/brazil.svg}
\includesvg[width={10\mypx}]{assets/images/flags/twemoji/italy.svg}
\includesvg[width={10\mypx}]{assets/images/flags/twemoji/portugal.svg}
\includesvg[width={10\mypx}]{assets/images/flags/twemoji/spain.svg}
```

Small log here:

```
No file minha-genealogia-completa-01.aux.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd) (|'inkscape' -V ) (./svg-inkscape/argentina_svg-tex.pdf_tex) (./svg-inkscape/brazil_svg-tex.pdf_tex) (./svg-inkscape/italy_svg-tex.pdf_tex) (./svg-inkscape/portugal_svg-tex.pdf_tex) (./svg-inkscape/spain_svg-tex.pdf_tex)

/home/Ooo/minha-genealogia-completa-01.tex:113: LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.113 ^^I^^I}
             
No pages of output.
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Please note that no one except you can run your code it seems, because we don't have access to your `assets/images/flags/twemoji/` folder.

Comment: I put the log here.

Comment: Follow the zipped file link: https://file.io/7Wap9bDziC7j

Comment: If you put a `\par` at the end of each of your entries you can't put a `\\ ` after your `\Ancestries`, because then you'd do `\par\\ ` and that throws the error in your question. Just remove the `\\ ` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error

```
LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.
```

is usually thrown if you use `\\` in vertical mode. In your case it is caused by the `\\` after `\Ancestries{argentina, brazil, italy, portugal, spain}`, because after each entry in `\Ancestries` you put a `\par`, so this essentially leads to `\par\\`, and then you're greeted with that error.

The following compiles:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\newlength{\mypx}
\setlength{\mypx}{0.013889in}

\newcommand\Ancestries[1]
  {%
    \foreach \ancestry in {#1}% 
      {%
        \rule{10\mypx}{10\mypx}\par
        %\includesvg[width={10\mypx}]{assets/images/flags/twemoji/\ancestry.svg}\par
      }%
  }

\begin{document}

    \linespread{1.5}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \genealogytree
        {
            parent
            {
                g[id = 01, male, box = {title = Self}]
                {
                    \textbf{Ancestries}\\
                    \Ancestries{argentina, brazil, italy, portugal, spain}
                }
            }
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```